# Pull data from SQL Server based on Excel Query

Tags: sql-server, excel, powerbi

I have a PowerBI report I am currently working on where I would like to use an existing query from an Excel file to pull specific data from a database on an SQL Server.

Example:
*Excel file has column named "Order" and is limited to 60 rows.*

*SQL server has an "Order" and "Sales" column and has 4 million rows.*

I would like to query the SQL server to only retrieve rows that match the 60 rows in my excel file.

I feel like this is something that is probably very simple and I'm overlooking it.

**EDIT**

I had forgotten that I changed my Excel file to an Access Database as I started to gather more data and append.

The two tables I am trying to connect look like this:

```
Access Database
ID  |Type  |OrderId  
1   | Sale | Order0001
2   | Sale | Order0002


SQL Server
OrderId  | Cost  |Sales  | StoreId
Order0001|  5.00 | 15.00 | 01
Order0002|  4.00 | 12.00 | 01
```

The Access DB has 67,000 rows and the SQL Server has ~ 4 million.  They share the OrderId column and I want to bring across only the 67,000 Orders from the Access DB when I query the SQL Server.

Comment: Are you having a problem with sql server querying excel? Or having a problem forming the query?

Comment: I'm having an issue forming the query.   My understanding of SQL is very limited.  I can write the SELECT FROM query  to get all orders, but I am not sure if I can do a WHERE clause and combine the Excel query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you need this "tricks". You will need to modify m code (right click on your table):

https://www.biinsight.com/quick-tips-how-to-filter-a-column-by-a-column-from-a-different-query-in-power-query/
https://www.aaronjgrossman.com/2020/01/25/filter-table-by-another-power-query/

The base is that:

```
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"PREVIOUS_STEP", each 
List.Contains(#"REFERENCED_TABLE"[REFERENCED_COLUMN], [COLUMN_TO_BE_FILTERED]))
```

This is something similar to SQL:

```
SELECT productsubcategorykey          
   , productsubcategoryalternatekey 
   , [Subcategory Name]
FROM   DimProductSubcategory
WHERE  [Subcategory Name] IN (SELECT [Approved Subcategory] 
                          FROM [Product Subcategory Lookup])
```

Comment: Thanks, I think this is going to get me to the right area.  I'm struggling to make it work right now but I'm going to keep working on it and see if I can get this.

Comment: This worked.  I may end up going a different direction because that query took ~20 minutes to complete and I'm not sure yet how often I'll need it to run, but this got me where I needed to be.

Answer (score 0):

You can index the table, for one thing.  Also, you can filter the data in SQL Server, and insert it into a helper table, then query that with Excel/VBA.  Accessing 76000 records will absolutely be much quicker than querying 4000000 records.  You can use PowerQuery to access data in SQL Server.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/import-data-from-database-using-native-database-query-power-query-f4f448ac-70d5-445b-a6ba-302db47a1b00

Also,PowerPivot is an option.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2414/introduction-to-powerpivot-for-excel-and-sql-server/

Finally, you can use VBA to do ths job.  This will probably be the slowest option.

```
Sub LoopThroughTable()

Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim Server_Name As String
Dim Database_Name As String
Dim User_ID As String
Dim Password As String
Dim SQLStr As String
Dim RS As ADODB.Recordset
Set RS = New ADODB.Recordset

Server_Name = "your_server_name"
Database_Name = "your_DB_name"
'User_ID = "******"
'Password = "****"

'loop through all cells in a range
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long

'lastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Set sht = ActiveSheet
LastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = Range("A1:A" & LastRow)

Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
Cn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & Server_Name & ";Database=" & Database_Name & ";"
'& ";Uid=" & User_ID & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";"

RS.Open SQLStr, Cn, adOpenStatic

    For Each cell In rng
    
    SQLStr = "select * from mytable1 Where ID = " & cell.Value
    
    Sheets.Add
    ActiveSheet.Move After:=Sheets(1)
    ActiveSheet.Name = cell.Value
    
        With ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
            .ClearContents
            .CopyFromRecordset RS
        End With
    
        wb.SaveAs "C:\your_path_here\" & cell.Value & " .xlsx"
    Next cell

RS.Close
Set RS = Nothing
Cn.Close
Set Cn = Nothing

End Sub
```